# How to have linear gradient background on all screens in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, linear-gradients

I have an app written in React Native. I would like to have a gradient background in all screens. Maybe something like:

[image]

I have found the `react-native-linear-gradient` package, but would I get higher performance using an image?

Also, how do I make sure it stays as a background on all pages?

Would it be something like

```
const Container = (props) => (
  <View>
    <LinearGradient colors=['blue', 'orange', 'blue'] />
    {props.children}
  </View>
);
```

and then on all my screens use

```
<Container>
  ..
</Container>
```

Comment: You can't use gradient as a color in React native, it does't allow, you can use lib for this : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create gradient image in some graphical editors which allow you to set linear gradient from  top(blue) to bottom(transparent), and place this image as background  all your scenes. Its can be helpful.
But if you need to cange colors of your gradient dynamically, you need to use libraries for now.